# pyserial- sending in parameters at runtime- input vs. raw_input - security flaw?

Tags: python, security, user-input, pyserial

I am writing a program that opens and records data sent through a serial port into a text file. I am currently adding functionality to allow reconfiguring the serial port during run-time. I prompt the user to choose which variable to change one at a time, so as to keep it simple for myself (i would appreciate elegant solutions as well).

The pyserial function that creates the serial instance (serial.Serial()) has the following parameters:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port=0, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=None, interCharTimeout=None) #default values shown
```

I notice that while most are int() arguments, some are not, i.e. "timeout".

I know using `int(raw_input("for the int() type variables))` would let me safely assign the int variables, but the variables with None as default would require an `input()` function to properly assign the possible None value.

I have read elsewhere that input() is generally not recommended, since it has potential for being exploited(something about eval()?). How then should i handle those inputs? i.e. using serial.Serial() where writeTimout = str(None) throws an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way is just to accept the user's input as a string and then parse it. I.e. let the user enter key=value pairs:

```
baudrate = 9600
parity = N
```

Then parse these pairs, by splitting on '=' and stripping both sides. Assign the variables with a string lookup table (the `baudrate` string maps to the `baudrate` var, and so on). This way you can handle the `None` value any way you want.

This method is simple and safe. `input` will raise exceptions if the user input isn't valid Python, and you may not want that.

Comment: I see, I will try that right now. 
Is it a better idea to have a text file with the two columns of the lookup table(i.e. a dictionary?) or should I just have it initialized when the program runs? Thanks for your time

Comment: @PPTim: if you're talking about a configuration file that's read by the program, use some of Python's existing options like ConfigParser